# Echo uploaded filename from database in no file chosen part

Tags: php, forms

I have form which includes a file upload.After the form is submitted the selected filename is saved in the database.And i have a edit form of saved data.In that form in the file upload button,at the position where shows "*no file chosen*" i need to echo the saved file form the database.

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-cloud-upload"></i>
    <label for="">File upload</label>
   <?php echo $announcements_details['file'] ; ?>
    <input type="file"  id="captionfile" name="captionfile"></div>\
    </div>
```

I need echo the `$announcements_details['file']` in the no file choose chosen part. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do this, due to security reasons. you would be able to select and upload any file from the client to your website.

However, you can display a message below it saying a file has been uploaded. Or you could override the input style using css and display the text that way.

Comment: Oh..thanks for the information Jerodev.So can you suggest me a way to change the text of the file upload button from choose file to "update file"

Comment: No, that is not possible either, you can't change the text. What you can do is make the input invisible using css and place a div under it with your own layout. In this div, you can place any text you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Jerodev said it is not possible to takeout the same file in place of the choose file button. But there is a work around for this.

- If the uploaded file is an image file, then you could pull up the filename from the database, and display a small thumbnail for the image below the choose upload button.
- And if it is any other file, (pdf/txt..etc.), then you could display a link to the file below the choose upload button, so that the users can download the file and see what they have uploaded.

Hope this helps.
Thanks.